# Ebean in Play 2.0 - No join on the generated query

Tags: playframework-2.0

I two classes set up this way:

```
public class Listing extends Model {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
    public User user;

    public String name;
}


public class User extends Model {    
    @Id
    @Constraints.Required
    @Formats.NonEmpty
    public String username;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="user")
    public List<Listing> listing;
}
```

The problem is that the query to return only the particular user's Listings does have a join in it as I would expect it to, but has something like:

```
select t0.name
from listing t0 
where t0.user_id = 'name@email.com'
```

Any idea of what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define explicity the join in order to fetch elements from the Listing table.

In the User class :

```
find.fetch("listing").findList();
```

Comment: Thanks Julien! I also made a mistake where I defined the '@Id' on the wrong field. '@Id' should be defined on public Long id; and not on the username.